# Name of Diagrams Used In OData URI Conventions Documentation

Tags: url, odata, diagramming

[The OData URI Conventions documentation](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions) uses some nice diagrams to visually explain the rules ([here's a direct example](http://www.odata.org/images/resourcePath.png)). Do these types of diagrams have a specific name? I'd like to find a tool that will help me create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [syntax diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram)

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you. That link just sparked my interest in the whole world of langauge design :)